# What is this: Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Recurrent Tasks for GTasks

Tags: google-apps-script

our script, Recurrent Tasks for GTasks, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

Summary:
Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.   2

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
10/5/22 3:01:43 AM GMT  processRecurrentLists   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  10/5/22 3:01:43 AM GMT
10/6/22 3:01:42 AM GMT  processRecurrentLists   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  10/6/22 3:01:43 AM GMT

Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2022 Google

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The error message you quote tells that you need to re-authorize the script project. The easiest way to do that is to go to the [My Triggers](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) dashboard, delete your existing trigger, and re-create it using settings that are identical to what the existing trigger has.

When you save the new trigger, you will be asked to authorize it, which should fix the issue.

See [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: What trigger should I add?

Comment: Based on the looks of the error message you quote, the existing trigger is a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). You can use the same parameters that you have in the existing trigger.

Comment: @jjv This seems like a good answer. You might want [to accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Help. I am unfamiliar with all this. Can I get clear and detailed way to go

Comment: You are asking for help with an Apps Script trigger. The answer above tells where to go to see the triggers, and how to recreate a trigger to get it to re-authorize. There is not much else that can be said about the issue because your question lacks debugging details.